# What does this error message mean in ASP.NET "Server Error in '/' Application."

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

Why do I keep getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: I think the Nuget package  `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`  is of wrong version. Try updating the Nuget package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is causing because the Nuget package `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` (which also contains the CodeAnalysis package) was the wrong version.

create new web application and update Nuget package.

Answer (score 2):

Try to uninstall and reinstall the package

```
Uninstall-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform -force
Install-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
```

Comment: This worked for me after trying regular uninstalls of the DotNetCompilerPlatform and re-installs.  I never used the `-force` command in previous attempts though.  I also ran a Clean Solution before re-installing the package.